# Resource request URL failing with 404

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have been working on a Wordpress page of mine. Made changes to WP Rocket plugin under the CSS and JS file optimization.

Lately in some of the pages, when I'm not logged in to Wordpress and not using VPN, some of my pages are not behaving correctly (clicks not working at places, UI layout distorted). I see in the network tab that some css/js file with path
`wp-content/cache/min/1/123454323567.js (.css)`
are failing with 404.

I saw that the project is already using a WP-Optimize plugin for JS optimization. I have since reverted my changes under WP Rocket for CSS/JS Optimization. Still the same issue of resources failing with 404.

Please help me with this. What is going wrong here ?

Comment: The best we can help you with is that you should clear ALL of your caches: browser, WP Rocket, WP-Optimize, and your server. My guess is one of those is trying to access a cached file that no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks @disinfor. Clearing cache from Cloudflare did the bit.